# How to show time in percentage in mode-line in emacs

Tags: emacs, time, percentage

If time is 08:00, emacs should display **33.3%** in modeline

and show **80.0%** when time is 19:12.

How can I do this in **.emacs**? thanks very much.

algorithm is **current-time/24**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @phils says, you can override the custom setting “Display Time String Forms”. In particular:

Go to the “Display Time” customization group and change the value of the “Display Time String Forms” setting to:

```
((format "%.1f%%"
   (* 100 (/ (+ (* (string-to-number 24-hours) 3600)
                (* (string-to-number minutes) 60)
                (string-to-number seconds))
             86400.0)))
)
```

Comment: exactly what I want, thanks very much. It works well. Should seed you two guys cakes before Christmas ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want `display-time-mode` to display the time in this way, you should look into the `display-time-string-forms` variable, which will enable you to perform any arbitrary processing. I don't think any of the simpler customisations provide for this particular approach.